# JSON use multiple keys for the same value in an object

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to use a `JSON` object that holds data in a similar fashion to

```
const obj = {
    key_a : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    key_b : [2, 8, 4, 0, 9, 5],
    key_c : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

as you can see `key_a` and `key_c` have the same data.

Idealy I would have something like

```
const obj = {
    [key_a, key_c] : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

or

```
const obj = {
    key_a : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    key_c : key_a
}
```

but offcourse these do not work.

Is there a way to "without merging" make the JSON object more `DRY`

my Solution at the moment is to use a variable that takes the key and uses a single key as such

```
input = (input === key_a || input === key_c) ? key_ac : input;
const obj = {
    key_ac : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    key_b : [2, 8, 4, 0, 9, 5]
}
```

This feel clumsy and also like there should be a better solution.
It also requires changing the key names, which I would also like to avoid.

Comment: Why do you need this and what exactly are you expecting? Please clear on your purpose.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed as I understand it, the rules do not allow for help to be specific to a single project, but wide spread enough that anyone with a simpilar problem can see what others have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) method for this,

```
const obj = {
    key_a : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    key_b : [2, 8, 4, 0, 9, 5],
    get key_c() { return this.key_a; }
}
```

Now if you console.log `obj.key_c` you will get the value of `obj.key_a`. So, now if you update `key_a` you don't have to update key_c as it is a getter. Whenever you try to get `obj.key_c` it will give you the latest `obj.key_a`.

Comment: I like this solution not sure why i didn't think about getters when I use them in classes all the time.